# Using this.setstate with Fetch API

Tags: reactjs, fetch, setstate

I'm trying to use a fetch call to retrieve some API data. Unfortunately I cannot use this to set the state.

```
consructor() {
    this.state = {
      weather: ""
    };

  this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  search(postalCode) {
    const url = `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?&postal_code=${postalCode}&key=${API_KEY}&days=7`;
    fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => console.log(data));
  }'
```

This code works fine, and prints an object to the console containing the correct data.

```
consructor() {
    this.state = {
      weather: ""
    };

  this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  search(postalCode) {
    const url = `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?&postal_code=${postalCode}&key=${API_KEY}&days=7`; 
    fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => this.setState({weather: data}))
     .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

As soon as I try to use the data to update my state, I get the "this.setState is not a function" error. I've bound the search function in the constructor.

I've even tried to bind it like this:

```
fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ weather: data })).bind(this);
```

This doesn't work either. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just wrap curly bracket { this.setState({your code}) } will work

Comment: Did you use `super()` in your `constructor`? if not, you have to

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your class definition, but I believe that using the state requires you to extend Component

The issue you are getting is that this component doesn't have the state functions in it.

Here's some code from a working project of mine using similar fetches, returned by the services:

```
type HomeProps = {}

type State = {
    projects: ProjectModel[],
    skills: SkillModel[],
    resume: JobModel[]
}

export default class Home extends Component<HomeProps, State> {
    private projectService: ProjectService;

    constructor(props: HomeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.projectService = new ProjectService();

        this.state = {
            projects: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getProjects();
    }

    private getProjects() {
        this.projectService.retrieveItems().then(projects => {
            this.setState({projects});
        })
    }
```

Here is the service:

```
export default class ProjectService {

    url = "http://api.flynndev.us";

    async retrieveItems() {
        return fetch(`${this.url}/projects/all`)
            .then(response => response.json());
    }

    async getItem(itemLink: string) {
        return fetch(`${this.url}/projects/${itemLink}`)
            .then(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using Typescript.  Feel free to ignore the typing stuff for regular React